# Better solvent for KCl than water?

Tags: water, experimental-chemistry, home-experiment

In my experiment, I used an atomizer to generate $\ce{KCl}$ aerosols. I saw that the nozzle that was dipped into the 10% wt $\ce{KCl}$ solution got partially clogged after an hour. I then had to disassemble the nozzle in order to clean it, which I did by rinsing it with water and drying it with a stream of air.
 Is there any way to avoid the clogging?

[image: see the attached photo]

Answer (score 2):

This seems like more of an engineering problem than "chemistry problem." I'm not sure how long you want the process to run, nor how critical the 10% salt concentration is.

I'd try adding a pure water bubbler in front of the salt solution to saturate the air being blown through with water.

Answer (score 2):

I'd agree with @MaxW that this is mostly an engineering problem.

Your best bet for increasing solubility would be to increase temperature; I don't think you'll find a solvent better than water for KCl, given how cheap/available it is.

[image: sols]

[image: sols2]

In general, increasing velocity of the particles will increase solubility (as Kinetic Energy increases). You may consider putting your solution on a stir plate or air-bubbler like @MaxW suggested.

If you're really looking for other solvents that may work better for your setup, stick to something highly polar.

Figures reference: http://pubs.acs.org.ezproxy.lib.usf.edu/doi/abs/10.1021/je049922y

Comment: It looks to me like the poster has a glass frit bubbler. I'm conjecturing that the back and forth motion of the fluid results in part of the solution becoming "trapped" in the frit by bubbles, and then drying out. The bubbles then insulate the solid salt preventing it from contacting the bulk of the solution. So I think the simple solution is to hydrate the gas before bubbling it through the salt solution.

Comment: Thanks, looks it might be the case and hydrating the gas is one solution. For now, in my experiments i've cleaned the stainless steel nozzle by dipping into to the boiling water. Apparently, this has fixed the problem.